# What is the meaning of this line from ssh output: 'Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling'?

Tags: ssh, authentication, ssh-keys, rhel8

Everything works, ssh connects using private-public ssh key pair.
Just few things in `ssh -v Ora2` output isn't clear for me.

This is complete `ssh -v Ora2` output:

```bash
PS C:\Users\roeslermichal> ssh -v Ora2
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug1: Reading configuration data C:\\Users\\roeslermichal/.ssh/config
debug1: C:\\Users\\roeslermichal/.ssh/config line 19: Applying options for Ora2
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to 10.32.81.218 [10.32.81.218] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\roeslermichal\\.ssh\\poczt_id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\roeslermichal\\.ssh\\poczt_id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_8.0 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 10.32.81.218:22 as 'michal'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\roeslermichal/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:jQ2i6lqzzZnhdPc+GKQCS6iiCD5W/2wDzhLvigIlytg
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\roeslermichal/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '10.32.81.218' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\roeslermichal/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\roeslermichal\\.ssh\\poczt_id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:eQBpsX9pvzP6RuorzRWhlK2s4sOEdj3KrgME3TGeSMU explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\roeslermichal\\.ssh\\poczt_id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:eQBpsX9pvzP6RuorzRWhlK2s4sOEdj3KrgME3TGeSMU explicit
debug1: Server accepts key: C:\\Users\\roeslermichal\\.ssh\\poczt_id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:eQBpsX9pvzP6RuorzRWhlK2s4sOEdj3KrgME3TGeSMU explicit
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 10.32.81.218 ([10.32.81.218]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: filesystem full
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT is supported. Reading the VTSequence from console
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING is supported. Console supports the ansi parsing
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching C:\\Users\\roeslermichal/.ssh/known_hosts for 10.32.81.218 / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: searching C:\\Users\\roeslermichal/.ssh/known_hosts2 for 10.32.81.218 / (none)
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: hostkeys file C:\\Users\\roeslermichal/.ssh/known_hosts2 does not exist
debug1: client_input_hostkeys: no new or deprecated keys from server
debug1: Remote: /home/michal/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
debug1: Remote: /home/michal/.ssh/authorized_keys:1: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
Activate the web console with: systemctl enable --now cockpit.socket
```

I understand most of it, but few lines require some explanation.

1. **`Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling`**
   I don't understand what `$SSH_SK_PROVIDER` is, and what wasn't resolved at this stage.
   What is getting disabled??
   I mean, ssh just read ssh config file from my Windows 11 laptop and applied `Ora2` settings.
   It's not even connected yet, so what authentication are we talking about so early in the process.
   What `$SSH_SK_PROVIDER` is ?
2. **Please explain these two lines for me:**
   SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
   SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
   I don't know what `SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT` is?
   Is it necessary?
   I'm just using private-public key pair authentication.
   Can I turn `SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT` off??

Comment: 2. that's the Key Exchange process - so, I think that is relevant to the type of authentication your are using

Comment: 1. at a guess, `$SSH_SK_PROVIDER` refers to an environment variable

Comment: look for SSH_SK_PROVIDER in the [release notes](https://www.openssh.com/releasenotes.html)